# Golang struct unmarshal xss

Tags: json, go, golang-migrate

I have a struct which has XSS injected in it. In order to remove it, I json.Marshal it, then run json.HTMLEscape. Then I json.Unmarshal it into a new struct.

The problem is the new struct has XSS injected still.

I simply can't figure how to remove the XSS from the struct. I can write a function to do it on the field but considering there is json.HTMLEscape and we can Unmarshal it back it should work fine, but its not.

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
func main() {
    var p, p2 Person
     // p.Name has XSS
    p.Name = "<script>alert(1)</script>"
    var tBytes bytes.Buffer

    // I marshal it so I can use json.HTMLEscape
    marshalledJson, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    json.HTMLEscape(&tBytes, marshalledJson)

    // here I insert it into a new struct, sadly the p2 struct has the XSS still 
    err := json.Unmarshal(tBytes.Bytes(), &p2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Print(p2)

}
```

expected outcome is p2.Name to be sanitized like `&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;`

Comment: check this code https://play.golang.org/p/GyXPEOefMnJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement XSS protection in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202894/implement-xss-protection-in-golang)

Comment: @AhmedHashem I'm aware of the html escape but I'm looking for the reason and solution how to escape it utilizing json.Unmarshal.

Answer (score 0):

First, [`json.HTMLEscape`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#HTMLEscape) doesn't do what you want:

> HTMLEscape appends to dst the JSON-encoded src with <, >, &, U+2028 and U+2029 characters inside string literals changed to \u003c, \u003e, \u0026, \u2028, \u2029 so that the JSON will be safe to embed inside HTML <script> tags.

but what you want is:

> p2.Name to be sanitized like `&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;`

which you can get by calling [`html.EscapeString`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/#EscapeString), but *not* by any of the json encoder routines.<sup>1</sup>

Second, if you inspect the result of `json.Marshal` you'll see that it has already replaced `<` with `\u003c` and so forth—it's already done the `json.HTMLEscape`, so `json.HTMLEscape` does not have any characters to replace!  See https://play.golang.org/p/Zergs3bwElY for an example.

As Ahmed Hashem noted, if you really want to do this sort of thing, you can use reflection to find string fields (as in [Implement XSS protection in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44202894/1256452))—but in general it's probably wiser to do this at the point of input.  Note that the answer there does not recurse into inner objects that might contain strings.

---

<sup>1</sup>JSON is not HTML, nor XML, etc.  Keep them separate in your head, and in your code.

See also https://medium.com/@oazzat19/what-is-the-difference-between-html-vs-xml-vs-json-254864972bbb, a short summary of how we got here that as far as I can tell has no errors, which is pretty good for a random web article. :-)  When using JSON, we get very simple typed data: objects, strings, numbers, lists/arrays, boolean, and null; see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp, and https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/basic_types/ for instance.